# Spotfire- Selecting data on one plot and deselected from the previous selection

Tags: graph, spotfire, multipleselection

I have two graphs on a single page. One is a histogram and the other a scatterplot. My intent is to use the two graphs to select data that I want to investigate further, i.e. generate a list of those selected data points.

I select data using a range of the histogram. Say this selection gives me 45 records, but I only want 30 records. How can I deselect some data points on the scatterplot? I want to use the scatterplot to narrow the 45 records by unselecting some of the points on the scatterplot. I've tried options like Invert, but that brings all the inversions from the histogram.

I think it has to do with Markings, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start by marking the bar chart, here is a suggestion.
First, make sure you have at least 2 Markings defined in the dxp.

To create new Markings, go to:
File > Document Properties > Markings > New..
Say your Markings are called Marking1 and Marking2.

Then assign Marking1 to the bar chart by doing this:
Properties > Data > Marking and selecting Marking1.

Similarly, in the scatterplot, you assign Marking2, but additionally make it limited by Marking1:

Properties > Data > Marking and selecting Marking2.
Properties > Data > Limit Data using Markings and selecting Marking1.

The result is that the bar chart marks with Marking1, and the scatterplot shows the data marked by the bar chart. The you can mark again the scatterplot to narrow down your selection.

Then create a third plot - a table. Make sure has marking (None) assigned (so you don’t accidentally undo your work) and it only shows points that are marked by both Marking1 and Marking2.

You do this again by using Limit Data using Markings and selecting Marking1 and Marking2.
Make sure they act as an AND (see option further down, the default).